# Adding listview/button-like style behavior to layouts in a repeater in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I've got a facebook like activity feed, and I'm using a repeater because I want to have multiple clickable items within each "activity", ie, clicking on the top portion goes to the users profile, vs. the body of the activity opens the activity, plus some links for comments, likes below that.

```
            <ScrollView  orientation="vertical">
                 <Repeater items="{{ activities }}">
                    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                         <StackLayout orientation="vertical" />
                    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>     
                        <StackLayout  tap="goProfile" >
                            <Image src="{{image}}" height="35" verticalAlignment="top" />
                            <Label text="{{user_name}}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout tap="goActivity">
                             ...
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                            <Image tap="addComment" src="{{comment}}" />
                            <Image tap="addLike" src="{{like}}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                     </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                 </Repeater>
             </ScrollView>
```

This is basically working fine, except tapping on any of the tappable items does not give any visual feedback, ie. briefly turning the background of the item grey, like it does with a ListView....

I can't figure out how to get this behavior on clickable layouts within my repeater? is this possible? is there another approach I should be following?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `Repeater` here, which would load all items up-front with no optimizations?

Comment: I'm loading the items 15 at a time right now anyway. Maybe repeater not optimal, but I'm trying to get the behavior described above and the listview doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Your UI may be come unresponsive as you load more items depending on your available memory. In my opinion you should try focusing on fixing your problem with ListView rather using a Repeater unless you are sure that the items may not grow more than 100 or something. If you still like to stick with Repeater, you may use plugins like [nativescript-ripple](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ripple) for touch effects.

Comment: So is there a way to have multiple tappable areas within a listview with the visual highlights, or would I still need to employ the ripple plugin? @Manoj

Comment: You may use buttons, that's tappable and will give you touch effect too. If you need a layout, then you need ripple plugin.